# upgrade to manifest 2 my chrome apps no longer functions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

my application for google chrome no longer works, i upgraded as oer google to manifest 2 but now the popup baloon no longer opens when the icon is clicked below are both manifest and script.

when menifest 1 was in place the box did not open fully, hopfully your expert advice can help

```
  {
  "name": "XE Currency Converter",
    "manifest_version": 2,

  "version": "2.3.2",
  "description": "An exchange rate based currency converter provided by XE.com",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "19.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  }
  }
```

my script

```
<style>
body {
  min-width:185px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  background:#E2E2E2

}

img {
  margin:5px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:183px;
  height:81px;
}

body {

width:0px;
  height:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
</style>

<html> 
   <head> 

   </head>

   <body>

<!-- XE.com Universal Currency Converter(tm) Input Page Starts -->
<!-- Copyright (c) 2005 XE.com. Unauthorized use prohibited. -->
<!-- Input Template Version 3.10 -->
<!-- You may reformat this page section, but do not delete lines or variables that start with an asterisk -->

<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi" target="_blank">

<P><TABLE WIDTH=100% CELLPADDING=1 CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=0  BGCOLOR=#000000><TR><TD ALIGN=CENTER>
<TABLE WIDTH=100% CELLPADDING=3 CELLSPACING=1 BORDER=0>

<TR VALIGN=TOP ALIGN=CENTER>
  <TD BGCOLOR=#013c66><B>
    <FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica">
    <FONT SIZE="+1" color="ffffff">xe.com&nbsp;
    Universal Currency Converter </FONT> <FONT SIZE="-1" color="ffffff"><SUP> &reg;</SUP></FONT>
    </FONT>
  </B></TD>
</TR>

<TR VALIGN=TOP ALIGN=Left>
  <TD VALIGN=MIDDLE ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFF>
  <TABLE CELLSPACING=3 CELLPADDING=2 BORDER=0 WIDTH=100%><TR>
  <TD><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica">
    <!XERC-UCC1-P1.1-R1>
    <div style="text-align: center;"><B>Convert this</B></div>
  </FONT></TD>
  <TD><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica">
    <!XERC-UCC1-P1.3-R1>
   <div style="text-align: center;">  <B>from this currency</B></div>
  </FONT></TD>
  <TD><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica">
    <!XERC-UCC1-P1.5-R1>
   <div style="text-align: center;">  <B></B></div>
  </FONT></TD>
    <TD><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica">
    <!XERC-UCC1-P1.5-R1>
   <div style="text-align: center;">  <B>into this currency.</B></div>
  </FONT></TD>

</TR>


<script type="text/javascript">
function save() {
save_options_from();
save_options_to();
}

function restore() {
restore_options_from();
restore_options_to();
}


// Saves options to localStorage.
function save_options_from() {
  var select = document.getElementById("FROM");
  var FROM = select.children[select.selectedIndex].value;
  localStorage["default_currency"] = FROM;


}

function save_options_to() {
  var select = document.getElementById("TO");
  var TO = select.children[select.selectedIndex].value;
  localStorage["default_currency_to"] = TO;


}

// Restores select box state to saved value from localStorage.
function restore_options_from() {
  var favorite = localStorage["default_currency"];
  if (!favorite) {
    return;
  }
  var select = document.getElementById("FROM");
  for (var i = 0; i < select.children.length; i++) {
    var child = select.children[i];
    if (child.value == favorite) {
      child.selected = "true";
      break;

    }
  }
}

function restore_options_to() {
  var favorite2 = localStorage["default_currency_to"];
  if (!favorite2) {
    return;
  }
  var select = document.getElementById("TO");
  for (var i = 0; i < select.children.length; i++) {
    var child = select.children[i];
    if (child.value == favorite2) {
      child.selected = "true";
      break;

    }
  }
}

</script>

<body onload="restore()">

<TR VALIGN=Top ALIGN=center>

  <TD><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Amount" VALUE="1" SIZE=10><BR>
    <!XERC-UCC1-P1.2-R2>
    <FONT SIZE=-1><B></B></FONT>
  </FONT></TD>

  <TD><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" SIZE=-1>
    <SELECT NAME="From" SIZE=5  id ="FROM">
      <OPTION VALUE="EUR" SELECTED>Euro EUR</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="USD">United States Dollars USD</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="GBP">United Kingdom Pounds GBP</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="CAD">Canada Dollars CAD</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="AUD">Australia Dollars AUD</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="JPY">Japan Yen JPY</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="INR">India Rupees INR</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="NZD">New Zealand Dollars NZD</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="CHF">Switzerland Francs CHF</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="ZAR">South Africa Rand ZAR</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="EUR">-- Top Currencies: --</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AED">AED - United Arab Emirates Dirham</OPTION> 
<OPTION VALUE="AFN">AFN - Afghan Afghani</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ALL">ALL - Albanian Lek</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AMD">AMD - Armenian Dram</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ANG">ANG - Dutch Guilder</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AOA">AOA - Angolan Kwanza</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ARS">ARS - Argentine Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AUD">AUD - Australian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AWG">AWG - Aruban or Dutch Guilder</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AZN">AZN - Azerbaijani New Manat</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BAM">BAM - Bosnian Convertible Marka</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BBD">BBD - Barbadian or Bajan Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BDT">BDT - Bangladeshi Taka</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BGN">BGN - Bulgarian Lev</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BHD">BHD - Bahraini Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BIF">BIF - Burundian Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BMD">BMD - Bermudian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BND">BND - Bruneian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BOB">BOB - Bolivian Boliviano</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BRL">BRL - Brazilian Real</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BSD">BSD - Bahamian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BTN">BTN - Bhutanese Ngultrum</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BWP">BWP - Botswana Pula</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BYR">BYR - Belarusian Ruble</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BZD">BZD - Belizean Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CAD">CAD - Canadian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CDF">CDF - Congolese Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CHF">CHF - Swiss Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CLP">CLP - Chilean Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CNY">CNY - Chinese Yuan Renminbi</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="COP">COP - Colombian Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CRC">CRC - Costa Rican Colon</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CUC">CUC - Cuban Convertible Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CUP">CUP - Cuban Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CVE">CVE - Cape Verdean Escudo</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CZK">CZK - Czech Koruna</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="DJF">DJF - Djiboutian Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="DKK">DKK - Danish Krone</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="DOP">DOP - Dominican Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="DZD">DZD - Algerian Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="EGP">EGP - Egyptian Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ERN">ERN - Eritrean Nakfa</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ETB">ETB - Ethiopian Birr</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="EUR">EUR - Euro</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="FJD">FJD - Fijian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="FKP">FKP - Falkland Island Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GBP">GBP - British Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GEL">GEL - Georgian Lari</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GGP">GGP - Guernsey Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GHS">GHS - Ghanaian Cedi</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GIP">GIP - Gibraltar Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GMD">GMD - Gambian Dalasi</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GNF">GNF - Guinean Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GTQ">GTQ - Guatemalan Quetzal</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GYD">GYD - Guyanese Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="HKD">HKD - Hong Kong Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="HNL">HNL - Honduran Lempira</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="HRK">HRK - Croatian Kuna</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="HTG">HTG - Haitian Gourde</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="HUF">HUF - Hungarian Forint</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="IDR">IDR - Indonesian Rupiah</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ILS">ILS - Israeli Shekel</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="IMP">IMP - Isle of Man Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="INR">INR - Indian Rupee</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="IQD">IQD - Iraqi Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="IRR">IRR - Iranian Rial</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ISK">ISK - Icelandic Krona</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="JEP">JEP - Jersey Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="JMD">JMD - Jamaican Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="JOD">JOD - Jordanian Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="JPY">JPY - Japanese Yen</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KES">KES - Kenyan Shilling</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KGS">KGS - Kyrgyzstani Som</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KHR">KHR - Cambodian Riel</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KMF">KMF - Comoran Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KPW">KPW - North Korean Won</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KRW">KRW - South Korean Won</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KWD">KWD - Kuwaiti Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KYD">KYD - Caymanian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KZT">KZT - Kazakhstani Tenge</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LAK">LAK - Lao or Laotian Kip</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LBP">LBP - Lebanese Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LKR">LKR - Sri Lankan Rupee</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LRD">LRD - Liberian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LSL">LSL - Basotho Loti</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LTL">LTL - Lithuanian Litas</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LVL">LVL - Latvian Lat</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LYD">LYD - Libyan Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MAD">MAD - Moroccan Dirham</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MDL">MDL - Moldovan Leu</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MGA">MGA - Malagasy Ariary</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MKD">MKD - Macedonian Denar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MMK">MMK - Burmese Kyat</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MNT">MNT - Mongolian Tughrik</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MOP">MOP - Macau Pataca</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MRO">MRO - Mauritanian Ouguiya</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MUR">MUR - Mauritian Rupee</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MVR">MVR - Maldivian Rufiyaa</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MWK">MWK - Malawian Kwacha</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MXN">MXN - Mexican Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MYR">MYR - Malaysian Ringgit</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MZN">MZN - Mozambican Metical</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="NAD">NAD - Namibian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="NGN">NGN - Nigerian Naira</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="NIO">NIO - Nicaraguan Cordoba</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="NOK">NOK - Norwegian Krone</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="NPR">NPR - Nepalese Rupee</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="NZD">NZD - New Zealand Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="OMR">OMR - Omani Rial</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PAB">PAB - Panamanian Balboa</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PEN">PEN - Peruvian Nuevo Sol</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PGK">PGK - Papua New Guinean Kina</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PHP">PHP - Philippine Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PKR">PKR - Pakistani Rupee</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PLN">PLN - Polish Zloty</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PYG">PYG - Paraguayan Guarani</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="QAR">QAR - Qatari Riyal</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="RON">RON - Romanian New Leu</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="RSD">RSD - Serbian Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="RUB">RUB - Russian Ruble</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="RWF">RWF - Rwandan Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SAR">SAR - Saudi or Saudi Arabian Riyal</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SBD">SBD - Solomon Islander Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SCR">SCR - Seychellois Rupee</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SDG">SDG - Sudanese Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SEK">SEK - Swedish Krona</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SGD">SGD - Singapore Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SHP">SHP - Saint Helenian Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SLL">SLL - Sierra Leonean Leone</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SOS">SOS - Somali Shilling</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SPL">SPL - Seborgan Luigino</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SRD">SRD - Surinamese Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="STD">STD - Sao Tomean Dobra</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SVC">SVC - Salvadoran Colon</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SYP">SYP - Syrian Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SZL">SZL - Swazi Lilangeni</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="THB">THB - Thai Baht</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TJS">TJS - Tajikistani Somoni</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TMT">TMT - Turkmenistani Manat</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TND">TND - Tunisian Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TOP">TOP - Tongan Pa'anga</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TRY">TRY - Turkish Lira</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TTD">TTD - Trinidadian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TVD">TVD - Tuvaluan Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TWD">TWD - Taiwan New Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TZS">TZS - Tanzanian Shilling</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="UAH">UAH - Ukrainian Hryvna</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="UGX">UGX - Ugandan Shilling</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="USD">USD - US Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="UYU">UYU - Uruguayan Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="UZS">UZS - Uzbekistani Som</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="VEF">VEF - Venezuelan Bolivar Fuerte</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="VND">VND - Vietnamese Dong</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="VUV">VUV - Ni-Vanuatu Vatu</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="WST">WST - Samoan Tala</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XAF">XAF - Central African CFA Franc BEAC</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XAG">XAG - Silver Ounce</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XAU">XAU - Gold Ounce</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XCD">XCD - East Caribbean Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XDR">XDR - IMF Special Drawing Rights</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XOF">XOF - CFA Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XPD">XPD - Palladium Ounce</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XPF">XPF - CFP Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XPT">XPT - Platinum Ounce</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="YER">YER - Yemeni Rial</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ZAR">ZAR - South African Rand</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ZMK">ZMK - Zambian Kwacha</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ZWD">ZWD - Zimbabwean Dollar</OPTION>
    </SELECT><BR></TD>
    <!XERC-UCC1-P1.4-R2>

    <TD VALIGN=MIDDLE>
    <FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">
    <input type="button" value="&#8660" onClick="swapVar(); window.location.reload();">
    </TD>


  </FONT>
  <TD><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" SIZE=-1>
    <SELECT NAME="To" SIZE=5 id ="TO">
      <OPTION VALUE="USD" SELECTED>United States Dollars USD</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="EUR">Euro EUR</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="GBP">United Kingdom Pounds GBP</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="CAD">Canada Dollars CAD</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="AUD">Australia Dollars AUD</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="JPY">Japan Yen JPY</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="INR">India Rupees INR</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="NZD">New Zealand Dollars NZD</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="CHF">Switzerland Francs CHF</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="ZAR">South Africa Rand ZAR</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="USD">-- Top Currencies: --</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AED">AED - United Arab Emirates Dirham</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AFN">AFN - Afghan Afghani</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ALL">ALL - Albanian Lek</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AMD">AMD - Armenian Dram</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ANG">ANG - Dutch Guilder</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AOA">AOA - Angolan Kwanza</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ARS">ARS - Argentine Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AUD">AUD - Australian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AWG">AWG - Aruban or Dutch Guilder</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="AZN">AZN - Azerbaijani New Manat</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BAM">BAM - Bosnian Convertible Marka</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BBD">BBD - Barbadian or Bajan Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BDT">BDT - Bangladeshi Taka</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BGN">BGN - Bulgarian Lev</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BHD">BHD - Bahraini Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BIF">BIF - Burundian Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BMD">BMD - Bermudian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BND">BND - Bruneian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BOB">BOB - Bolivian Boliviano</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BRL">BRL - Brazilian Real</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BSD">BSD - Bahamian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BTN">BTN - Bhutanese Ngultrum</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BWP">BWP - Botswana Pula</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BYR">BYR - Belarusian Ruble</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BZD">BZD - Belizean Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CAD">CAD - Canadian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CDF">CDF - Congolese Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CHF">CHF - Swiss Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CLP">CLP - Chilean Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CNY">CNY - Chinese Yuan Renminbi</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="COP">COP - Colombian Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CRC">CRC - Costa Rican Colon</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CUC">CUC - Cuban Convertible Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CUP">CUP - Cuban Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CVE">CVE - Cape Verdean Escudo</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CZK">CZK - Czech Koruna</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="DJF">DJF - Djiboutian Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="DKK">DKK - Danish Krone</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="DOP">DOP - Dominican Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="DZD">DZD - Algerian Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="EGP">EGP - Egyptian Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ERN">ERN - Eritrean Nakfa</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ETB">ETB - Ethiopian Birr</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="EUR">EUR - Euro</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="FJD">FJD - Fijian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="FKP">FKP - Falkland Island Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GBP">GBP - British Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GEL">GEL - Georgian Lari</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GGP">GGP - Guernsey Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GHS">GHS - Ghanaian Cedi</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GIP">GIP - Gibraltar Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GMD">GMD - Gambian Dalasi</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GNF">GNF - Guinean Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GTQ">GTQ - Guatemalan Quetzal</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="GYD">GYD - Guyanese Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="HKD">HKD - Hong Kong Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="HNL">HNL - Honduran Lempira</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="HRK">HRK - Croatian Kuna</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="HTG">HTG - Haitian Gourde</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="HUF">HUF - Hungarian Forint</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="IDR">IDR - Indonesian Rupiah</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ILS">ILS - Israeli Shekel</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="IMP">IMP - Isle of Man Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="INR">INR - Indian Rupee</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="IQD">IQD - Iraqi Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="IRR">IRR - Iranian Rial</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ISK">ISK - Icelandic Krona</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="JEP">JEP - Jersey Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="JMD">JMD - Jamaican Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="JOD">JOD - Jordanian Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="JPY">JPY - Japanese Yen</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KES">KES - Kenyan Shilling</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KGS">KGS - Kyrgyzstani Som</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KHR">KHR - Cambodian Riel</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KMF">KMF - Comoran Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KPW">KPW - North Korean Won</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KRW">KRW - South Korean Won</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KWD">KWD - Kuwaiti Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KYD">KYD - Caymanian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="KZT">KZT - Kazakhstani Tenge</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LAK">LAK - Lao or Laotian Kip</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LBP">LBP - Lebanese Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LKR">LKR - Sri Lankan Rupee</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LRD">LRD - Liberian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LSL">LSL - Basotho Loti</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LTL">LTL - Lithuanian Litas</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LVL">LVL - Latvian Lat</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="LYD">LYD - Libyan Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MAD">MAD - Moroccan Dirham</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MDL">MDL - Moldovan Leu</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MGA">MGA - Malagasy Ariary</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MKD">MKD - Macedonian Denar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MMK">MMK - Burmese Kyat</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MNT">MNT - Mongolian Tughrik</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MOP">MOP - Macau Pataca</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MRO">MRO - Mauritanian Ouguiya</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MUR">MUR - Mauritian Rupee</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MVR">MVR - Maldivian Rufiyaa</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MWK">MWK - Malawian Kwacha</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MXN">MXN - Mexican Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MYR">MYR - Malaysian Ringgit</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MZN">MZN - Mozambican Metical</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="NAD">NAD - Namibian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="NGN">NGN - Nigerian Naira</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="NIO">NIO - Nicaraguan Cordoba</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="NOK">NOK - Norwegian Krone</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="NPR">NPR - Nepalese Rupee</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="NZD">NZD - New Zealand Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="OMR">OMR - Omani Rial</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PAB">PAB - Panamanian Balboa</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PEN">PEN - Peruvian Nuevo Sol</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PGK">PGK - Papua New Guinean Kina</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PHP">PHP - Philippine Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PKR">PKR - Pakistani Rupee</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PLN">PLN - Polish Zloty</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PYG">PYG - Paraguayan Guarani</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="QAR">QAR - Qatari Riyal</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="RON">RON - Romanian New Leu</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="RSD">RSD - Serbian Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="RUB">RUB - Russian Ruble</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="RWF">RWF - Rwandan Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SAR">SAR - Saudi or Saudi Arabian Riyal</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SBD">SBD - Solomon Islander Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SCR">SCR - Seychellois Rupee</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SDG">SDG - Sudanese Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SEK">SEK - Swedish Krona</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SGD">SGD - Singapore Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SHP">SHP - Saint Helenian Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SLL">SLL - Sierra Leonean Leone</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SOS">SOS - Somali Shilling</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SPL">SPL - Seborgan Luigino</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SRD">SRD - Surinamese Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="STD">STD - Sao Tomean Dobra</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SVC">SVC - Salvadoran Colon</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SYP">SYP - Syrian Pound</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SZL">SZL - Swazi Lilangeni</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="THB">THB - Thai Baht</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TJS">TJS - Tajikistani Somoni</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TMT">TMT - Turkmenistani Manat</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TND">TND - Tunisian Dinar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TOP">TOP - Tongan Pa'anga</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TRY">TRY - Turkish Lira</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TTD">TTD - Trinidadian Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TVD">TVD - Tuvaluan Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TWD">TWD - Taiwan New Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TZS">TZS - Tanzanian Shilling</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="UAH">UAH - Ukrainian Hryvna</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="UGX">UGX - Ugandan Shilling</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="USD">USD - US Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="UYU">UYU - Uruguayan Peso</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="UZS">UZS - Uzbekistani Som</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="VEF">VEF - Venezuelan Bolivar Fuerte</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="VND">VND - Vietnamese Dong</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="VUV">VUV - Ni-Vanuatu Vatu</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="WST">WST - Samoan Tala</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XAF">XAF - Central African CFA Franc BEAC</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XAG">XAG - Silver Ounce</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XAU">XAU - Gold Ounce</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XCD">XCD - East Caribbean Dollar</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XDR">XDR - IMF Special Drawing Rights</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XOF">XOF - CFA Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XPD">XPD - Palladium Ounce</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XPF">XPF - CFP Franc</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="XPT">XPT - Platinum Ounce</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="YER">YER - Yemeni Rial</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ZAR">ZAR - South African Rand</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ZMK">ZMK - Zambian Kwacha</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="ZWD">ZWD - Zimbabwean Dollar</OPTION>
    </SELECT><BR>
    <!XERC-UCC1-P1.6-R2>

  </FONT></TD>

</TR>

<TR ALIGN=CENTER>
  <TD COLSPAN=100% ALIGN=CENTER>
  <FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" size=-1> <B>Scroll down to see more currencies</B></FONT>
  </TR>

<TR ALIGN=CENTER>
  <TD COLSPAN=100% ALIGN=CENTER><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">
    <!XERC-UCC1-P3.2-R1>
    <INPUT VALUE="Perform Currency Conversion" type=submit onClick="save()">

    <input type="button" value="Set Default Conversion" onClick="set(); window.location.reload();">


<script type="text/javascript"> 
function swapVar() {

var originalDefault = localStorage['default_currency'];
localStorage['default_currency'] = localStorage['default_currency_to'];
localStorage['default_currency_to'] = originalDefault;

}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function set() {
save_options_from();
save_options_to();
}

function restore() {
restore_options_from();
restore_options_to();
}


// Saves options to localStorage.
function save_options_from() {
  var select = document.getElementById("FROM");
  var FROM = select.children[select.selectedIndex].value;
  localStorage["default_currency"] = FROM;


}

function save_options_to() {
  var select = document.getElementById("TO");
  var TO = select.children[select.selectedIndex].value;
  localStorage["default_currency_to"] = TO;


}

// Restores select box state to saved value from localStorage.
function restore_options_from() {
  var favorite = localStorage["default_currency"];
  if (!favorite) {
    return;
  }
  var select = document.getElementById("FROM");
  for (var i = 0; i < select.children.length; i++) {
    var child = select.children[i];
    if (child.value == favorite) {
      child.selected = "true";
      break;

    }
  }
}

function restore_options_to() {
  var favorite2 = localStorage["default_currency_to"];
  if (!favorite2) {
    return;
  }
  var select = document.getElementById("TO");
  for (var i = 0; i < select.children.length; i++) {
    var child = select.children[i];
    if (child.value == favorite2) {
      child.selected = "true";
      break;

    }
  }
}
</script>


  </FONT></TD>
</TR>
</TD></TR></TABLE>

<TR ALIGN=CENTER>
  <TD BGCOLOR=#feef92 ALIGN=CENTER><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" SIZE=-1 COLOR=#808080>
    <!-- Important Section Start -->
    <!-- ALL of the contents of this section are required under the usage agreement! -->
    <FONT COLOR=#2d2d2d ><B>Universal Currency Converter</B> under license from <B>XE.com</B>. <A HREF="http://www.xe.com/legal/" style="color:#808080;" target="_blank">Terms of Use</A>
    <!-- Important Section Ends -->
  </FONT></TD>
</TR>

</TABLE>
</TD></TR></TABLE></P>

<!-- XE.com Universal Currency Converter(tm) Input Page Ends -->

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [google chrome extension- popup page not showing correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599365/google-chrome-extension-popup-page-not-showing-correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extract the scripts into a separate file when using manifest v. 2. See [Chrome extension documents](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) on Google sites for more