# $(document).ready doesn't work in chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, popup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [google chrome extension- popup page not showing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599365/google-chrome-extension-popup-page-not-showing-correctly)

I have this simple code in popup.html

In the head:

```
<script src='jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        foo();
    });
    function foo() {
        document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = "Hi, I entered foo";
    }
</script>
```

At the body:

```
<div id="popup">        <!--place holder-->
</div>
```

I was expected to get the string "Hi ..." in the opened slide when clicking the extension's icon. In fact, an empty slide is opened. Could anyone please explain what is wrong here?

(The jquery file named jquery-1.8.2.js is placed at the same folder as popup.html)

EDIT: After getting feedback, I moved the second script to an external file, as follows:

```
<script src='popup.js'></script>
```

popup.js:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        foo();
    });
    function foo() {
        document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = "Hi, I entered foo";
    }
</script>
```

But it's still not working. Why?

Comment: Are you sure your script tag is pointing to your jquery file? As far as I can see, there isn't any problem with your code

Comment: Yeah I saw after. But still, there isn't any problem with the code posted by the op

Comment: @RobW, I tried to put it in an external js file and it's still not working.

Comment: @Rapher From the information you've provided, that's impossible. Are you certain that the extension has been loaded correctly? Can you show the relevant source code of your extension?

Comment: @BrunoVieira, What do you mean to ask, can you please suggest a reason that might cause it to not point to the jquery file? Or, how can I check it out?

Comment: Your script is looking for the file `jquery-1.8.2.js` in the same directory of your html file. Are you sure you have this `jquery-1.8.2.js` file in the same directory?

Comment: @RobW, Thanks for responding. What do you mean by showing the source code. this is the only code of the popup, except for a style tag that I'm not allowed to post here. There are more background files, could they affect the popup loading in any way?

Comment: @Rapher Remove those `<script>` and `</script>` from `popup.js`.

Comment: also you should wrap your jQuery in (function($) { ..... })(jQuery)

Comment: and try to do things the jquery way, like $('#popup').append('<p>Hi, I entered foo</p>');

Comment: @infensus Your first suggestion is redundant, because `jQuery === $` by default. The wrapper is usually needed in jQuery plugin development only.

Comment: @RobW It is better to wrap any jQuery in this because of potential conflicts with other libraries, potentially 3rd party code using jQuery.noConflict, some of the worlds most popular cms' like Drupal globally undefining it, undefined behaviour after aggregation if you code isn't wrapped in a function, sorry for advising good practice.