# How do I implement jQuery UI in a chrome extension

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

I'm having a lot of trouble implementing jQueryUI in my chrome extension. I want to implement a selectable in my options page.

The chrome extension is a browser action that when clicked redirects the page to a cached version. In my options page, I will let the user choose which cache database to use e.g. Google, Yahoo, Bing, etc.. I want to let them choose via a selectable.

selectable: http://jqueryui.com/selectable/

I'm trying to implement a bare bones version of the selectable- basically just the demo they have, and then I'll build my webpage around the working version, but I can't seem to get it to work.

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "WebCache",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "description": "View a cached version of a web page",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19":"/images/icon.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Cache Page"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "redirect.js"
        ]
    },

    "options_page": "options.html",

    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

options.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Selectable - Serialize</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="options.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/demos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/jquery.ui.base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/jquery.ui.core.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/jquery.ui.selectable.css">
    <script src="options.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery.ui.selectable.js"></script>

    <style>
    #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
    #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
    #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
    #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
    #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
            stop: function() {
                var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
                $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                    var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
                    result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="feedback">
<span>You've selected:</span> <span id="select-result">none</span>.
</p>

<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

I've pretty much just cut and pasted demo code (and added references to more javascript files), so I'm quite confused as to why it's not working. Right now it displays a list with properly formatted CSS as it does in the example, but the javascript isn't working. Any help is seriously appreciated.

Many thanks,
Daniel

EDIT 2:

The javascript works in my editor Coda, but still not in the extension. The css all shows correctly in the extension though.

Comment: Did you follow the chrome extension guide for how to refer the css and js.

Comment: maybe its bullsh** but does the order have some relevance "jQuery/jquery.ui.core.js", "jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js" ??

Comment: This kind of question has been asked and answered before: [google chrome extension- popup page not showing correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599365/google-chrome-extension-popup-page-not-showing-correctly/11599420#11599420).

Answer (score 1):

You specified the ressources as content scripts. You don't need to do that if you want to use them only in the options page.

Maybe you can find the correct path to link the ressources when you consult the devtools' network-tab.
Are there any 404's?

Be sure, that you link the ressources relative from your options.html

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for teaching me about the devtools' network-tab; the css now shows up properly. I've updated my question, but it's still not working even though all the javascript is working. Any more hints?